# external javascript stopping page load

Tags: javascript

we have a piece of code placed on our website (somewhere within the  tags) that calls an external .cgi file

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.externaldomain.com/cgi-bin/file.cgi?foo=bar"></script>
```

This script records some data and then outputs the following code

```
document.write('<a href="http://www.link.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.externaldomain.com/image/banner.jpg" height=60 width=468 alt="foobar"/></a>');
```

This in turn displays the image.

The problem we have is that the file.cgi is on an external server and can not be moved to our server. If that server has downtime we find that it stops the rest of the page loading. Is there any way around this?

EDIT - more info after reading comments

The server the .cgi file is on would hang before timing out when we were having this issue.

I also tried adding async to the javascript call but got the following warning in the dubugging console

```
A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.
```

Regards

Comment: If that image is dynamic no. You'd could provide a placeholder img fallback if that request fails.

Comment: Why does it prevent the rest of the page loading? Surely a 404 code would be returned, and the page would continue to load.

Comment: That's what I thought Curt but apparently not, I have not witnessed the problem I am going by the info I have been told

Answer (score 0):

When the external server has downtime, perhaps their host sends a downtime notice with an improper 200 response code.

Perhaps the script returns like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Downtime!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>sorry, cheap-ass hosting is experiencing some downtime. Cheerio!</p>
    </body>
    </html>
</script>
```

Of course, that is a syntax error and would cause some browsers to blow up.

---

Seeing how the external service might hang for several minutes, you should load that script asynchronously like this:

```
<script async language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.externaldomain.com/cgi-bin/file.cgi?foo=bar"></script>
```

The `async` attribute tells the browser to keep loading the next script without waiting for this one to finish first.

See [a broswer compatibility chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Browser_compatibility) for async.

---

One last thing to try is writing your own proxy for that service. It would be easy enough in node.js: http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/

You could modify it so that it would send a request to external_domain.com, strip the document.write, and replace it with something useful.

Comment: The server in question would hang before timing out

Comment: I tried that earlier but get the following message in debug console:-
`A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.`